# Align avatars vertically on a scoreboard using css and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I would like to vertically align avatar images on a score board using an unordered list, so they are always nicely put one under the other. The problem is that when the number that takes more space such as 100., the avatar gets pushed out of the place onto the right side. The problem grows if I want to put something in front of the first numbers, for example a medal icon or similar.

Is there a way to keep these aligned and responsive, using jquery/js or css? Here's my code and codepen link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRyama

html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 right__column">
  <ul id="table" class="tableList">
    <p class="tableHeader">Results</p>
    <br>
    <h5 class="tableHeader__name">Scoreboard</h5>
    <hr class="line">
    <li><span class="numbers">1.</span> <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=6&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50" alt="kitten"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">10 points</span> </li>
    <hr class="line">
    <li><span class="numbers">2.</span> <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=6&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50" alt="kitten"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">9 points</span> </li>
    <hr class="line">
    <li><span class="numbers">3.</span> <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=6&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50" alt="kitten"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">8 points</span> </li>
    <hr class="line">
    <li><span class="numbers">4.</span> <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=6&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50" alt="kitten"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">7 points</span> </li>
    <hr class="line">
    <li><span class="numbers">5.</span> <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=6&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50" alt="kitten"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">6 points</span> </li>
    <hr class="line">
    <li><span class="numbers">6.</span> <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=6&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50" alt="kitten"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">5 points</span> </li>
    <hr class="line">
    <li><span class="numbers">7.</span> <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=6&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50" alt="kitten"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">4 points</span> </li>
    <hr class="line line__margin">
    <li class="dots text-center"><span>&bull;&bull;&bull;</span></li>
    <hr class="line line__margin--bottom">
    <li><span class="numbers">20.</span> <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=6&txt=50%C3%9750&w=50&h=50" alt="kitten"><span class="name"> John Doe</span><span class="numbers__points pull-right">3 points</span> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.right__column {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 36px;
}

.tableHeader {
  font-size: 160%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white;
}

.tableHeader__name {
  color: white;
  font-size: 110%;
}

.name {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.tableHeader__points {
  color: white;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dots {
  font-size: 280%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: black;
  //margin: -10%;
}

.line {
  color: blue;
  border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color;
}

.line__margin {
  margin-bottom: -3%;
}

.line__margin--bottom {
  margin-top: -3%;
}

.numbers {
  color: white;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.numbers__points {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to set width to your `.numbers` like a 50px and make its `display` to `inline-block`.
And then change the `text-align` to right. So even if the number is 9999 , it will fit exactly. Increasing the width can adjust the visibility of the numbers

```
.numbers {
    color: white;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Add the line with css. remove the '|' from the markup, and replace the gradient class with the following

```
.gradient {
    background: yellow;
    height: 40px;
    width: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can adjust the line upward and downward with `margin-bottom:-10px;` (adjust the value accordingly)

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please take a look on this if you catch time? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqdjRd?editors=1100   So I am trying to put a vertical line 50px height and 15px width in front of the first two numbers, which could later be put into gradient via css. I have tried with " | " but it doesn't work as supposed

Answer (score 1):

You can fix with with of the number element:

```
.numbers {
  color: white;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Arun I have used your code to style it till now and it worked very nice, could you perhaps check how could I put the line in front of first two number? I have explained the situation in the comment under:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqdjRd?editors=1100  thank you for all help!

Answer (score 1):

I have added this and nothing else

```
img{position:absolute;
display:inline-block;
top:-8px;
left:20%;
margin-left:20px;
}
```

Link:
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/jAxAEz

And I have set the li to position:relative.

This fixes only the image issue, but gives you an idea how to fix the rest, as you did not exactly specify what to do with the rest, tell us what to do and I'll ammend it. Just added the number class css from the reply under mine, credit to nimpooh, however this still would not take care of lengthy usernames, but really, the rest is very simple now.

Comment: all answers were very helpful, thank you! the most important thing was to align the avatars which works now, and now I will try to put some additional icons such as medals, but in front of the numbers, such as: [medal icon] 2. [avatar] John Doe 9 points, while keeping the avatars aligned

Comment: Just make sure to give the avatar groups classes instead of pointing to the img css settings.

Comment: I am now trying to put a vertical line or a shape in front of the first two numbers, for example 50px height and 15px width, which I would later stylize with the css with gradient for example. I have tried with the " | " symbol, but the problem is that is pushes the number to the right, so the rest of the numbers and avatars are not aligned. this is what it looks now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqdjRd?editors=1100

Comment: Ill do that and make it perfect tonight:-)

Comment: if you can I'll send you a beer :) here's an illustration what am I trying to do, maybe it will be helpful: http://sketchtoy.com/67287993  (but only for first 2-3 items, the other ones just need to be in vertical order considering their data)